# DriverManager keeps returning null connection only on Tomcat (works fine on Glassfish)

Tags: mysql, tomcat, null, glassfish, centos7

I am having a weird situation after upgrading Tomcat 7 to 7.0.26 (Centos 7 yum update) a few days ago. `DriverManager` fails to automatically recognize the MySQL driver and returns a null db `Connection` when the servlet is deployed on Tomcat server. On the other hand, GlassFish server on my NetBeans works totally fine.

The simple test servlet code is like below:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
    {
        Connection c = MySQLConnector.connect("DBFoobar", "username", "passwd");
        String message = null;
        if (c == null)
            message = "Connection returned null";
        else
            message = "C is returned: " + c.toString();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println(message);
        .
        .
        .
```

and in `MySQLConnector`, the `jdbc` call is defined like below:

```
public class MySQLConnector
{
    private static final String dbURLPrefix
            = "jdbc:mysql://dbfoobar.xxx.uswest2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/";
    public static Connection connect(String dbName, String username, String password)
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURLPrefix + dbName 
                + "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false", username, password);
           .
           .
           .
```

When the servlet is run on GlasshFish server, it correctly displays `Connection` object, but displays `Connection returned null` message on Tomcat server.

Any ideas on this? So far, I have tried to put mysql connector jar file under `/usr/share/tomcat/lib` directory but to no avail. The `war` package correctly contains the mysql connector jar file. The previous version of Tomcat 7 worked fine.

Comment: It didn't return null. It threw an exception. Your code returned null, but that's its fault. The exception tells you what the problem was.

Comment: No it did return null. With SELinux disabled, it works fine without any exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. It was due to SELinux. I have not checked the details, but SELinux seems to prevent `DriveManager` from executing. I modified the configuration file `/etc/selinux/config` and disabled SELinux:

```
SELINUX=permissive    # changed from enforcing
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay. I am giving up. :) The only things I was able to find out are as follows. I am using CentOS 7.

- Upgrade from Tomcat `7.0.69` to `7.0.76` seems to have broken the `Connection` generation from `DriverManager`
- From the `/var/log/yum.log`, OpenJDK (1.8.0) has also been upgraded
- After reverting the entire virtual EC2 instance to a previous backup (with Tomcat `7.0.69`), the code runs without any problem
- `yum update` again results in the error above

Hope this helps.